# How to remove special characters from a csv file in unix

Tags: unix, sed, awk, special-characters, bcp

i am facing hard time in removing the special characters from the csv file .

My process like this in my output table i have some data like this

```
Col1 
BC,BS/APP
```

Like this i have another 10 columns where there is a chance of getting the special characters when i tried with patindex i'm able to remove only first special character and for removing the other characters i need to use while loop which is taking hard time to do that .

So i tried to remove the special characters after bcping the data to the csv file below is the bcp command i am using

```
bcp_with_error_check tempdb..STT_IM166_WEB_MWE out temp.dat -SSVR -UUSR -PPWD -c -b1000 -t'","'
sed -e 's/,"0/,="0/g;s/,"1/,="1/g;s/,"2/,="2/g;s/,"3/,="3/g;s/,"4/,="4/g;s/,"5/,="5/g;s/,"6/,="6/g;s/,"7/,="7/g;s/,"8/,="8/g;s/,"9/,="9/g'temp.dat > temp1.dat
sed -e 's/$/"/g' temp1.dat > temp2.dat
sed -e 's/^/="/g' temp3.dat >>Filename.csv
```

My problem is since it is CSV file if i remove comma (,) considering as special character it is disturbing the file layout .

i can replace comma alone in data base but i am not getting the command to exclude the comma alone and remove other charachters . Please help me out i am in very need of this command

Comment: Which part of this removes commas?

Comment: How do you know when the first column contains a comma vs when the first comma marks the end of the first field?  Do you know that the second field is always numeric?

Comment: Here i did not included that code of removing commas @Beta

Comment: No i just included one example of column it is not always that col1 should contain comma or any other character . if it contains any special character how to handle it @jonathan leffler

Comment: If there's to be an automatic way to fix the 'commas in an ordinary field' in comma-separated output, there has to be a way to spot them.  How do you know when you have a comma in the body of a field as opposed to separating two fields?  There must be something that tells you...so you have to tell the computer how to recognize it too.  Without knowing a lot more about your data than we do, it is not really possible to help much more.  It is not a readily tractable problem.  Have you checked the BCP manual to ensure there isn't a way to get proper CSV output?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear what you're really after, but at the very least you can shrink your first `sed` command by a factor of 10:

```
sed -e 's/,"\([0-9]\)/,="\1/g' temp.dat > temp1.dat
```

The pattern looks for comma, double quote and a digit (and remembers what the digit is); it is replaced by comma, equals, double quote and the remembered digit.

Unless you have a reason for the different temporary files, you can collapse the three `sed` commands into one with:

```
sed -e 's/,"\([0-9]\)/,="\1/g' -e 's/$/"/g' -e 's/^/="/g' temp.dat >>Filename.csv
```

And if `bcp_with_error_check` will write to standard output if you omit the `out temp.dat` arguments, then you don't need any temporary files (which is generally a good idea).  Note that if two people innocently ran this command at the same time in the same directory, they'd be trampling over each other's temporary files (or running into problems because they couldn't).  With no temporary files, you've only got the final file name, `Filename.csv` to worry about.

However, that does not address your main question — it just improves your scripting.

Comment: THanks for your comments and i will note it But my main problem is to remove the Special characters without disturbing the csv layout .